# What is the logic behind allowing constant lvalue reference to bind to rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the logic behind allowing constant lvalue reference to bind an rvalue? In what situations I will need to do this:

```
const std::string& r2 = s1 + s1;
```

instead of this:

```
std::string&& r3 = s1 + s1;
```

Comment: It's seldom you need to do `const std::string& r2 = s1 + s1`, but think instead of passing the expression as an argument to a function? Like e.g. `std::cout << "The result is " << s1 + s2 << '\n'`. That will invoke a call to an `operator<<` function passing `s1 + s2` as argument to it.

Comment: @StenSoft [Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) disagrees with you.

Comment: @StenSoft, very wrong.

Comment: I think, nowadays variant 2 is preferred. But first example was valid even before rvalue references were thought of :)

Comment: @NathanOliver, by just having an rvalue reference sitting there no move constructor would be invoked.

Comment: @SergeyA Brain must not be fully booted up yet.

Comment: @SergeyA so I guess it is only another way to avoid "dangling-reference error". Besides being able to modify the second variant, do you know of any other differences?